# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused golang docker containers

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to make an http request from one project to another both using GO. The project that is making the request has the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o main .
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build .
CMD ["./main"]
```

The project that is waiting for the request is running on localhost:8000 and it has the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13.8 AS build-env
ADD . /dockerdev
WORKDIR /dockerdev
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go build -o /server
# Final stage
FROM debian:buster
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build-env /server /
CMD ["/server"]
```

When I make

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8000/orders", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
```

it gives me the following error

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused

I am new to docker so any improvements are welcome!

Comment: `127.0.0.1` localhost  in the second docker container will just point to the container itself - not the host itself. Drop the hostname & just list the port i.e. `:8000` and ensure the port is passed through to the host OS.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand...

Comment: Docker containers have independent network stacks. For all intends and purposes you can consider them to be different computers in this regard. Consequently, localhost in one container is a different network interface from localhost in another container. See https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/.

Comment: You can create your own network and connect those two container or you can use the `--link` option. Check the config with `docker inspect <name-of-container>`  and check Networks. It should have the same gateway.

Comment: [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a useful technology for orchestrating multiple docker containers and linking their networks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on my comment. Your client code's network address will not work:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8000/orders", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody)) // broken
```

as it is literally talking to itself (`localhost` refer to the *client* docker container - *not* the host OS).

---

The quickest way - for testing purposes - to expose the two containers to your host OS would be like so:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8000:8000 dockweb  # server container
docker run -it --rm --net host dockcli    # client container
```

Beyond trivial testing, this can quickly get unwieldy. So I recommend using things like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) which allows you to trivially link containers and their networks.

Comment: 2020/09/13 18:24:47 Post "http://:8000/orders": dial tcp :8000: connect: connection refused

Comment: @fbarril updated answer with some short & long term suggestions.

Comment: How would you do this with something running (say, a .Net Kestrel web server running locally) that is not in a container? It's weird, because I've had things not in containers that can freely talk to Redis, Elastic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. This should resolve the connection refused error.