# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused. go docker app

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two apps in go language. user_management app, which I run (docker-compose up --build) first, then I run(docker-compose up --build) sport_app. sport_app is dependent from user_management app.

**sport_app Dockerfile file as below.**

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git openssh curl

WORKDIR /go-sports-entities-hierarchy

COPY . /go-sports-entities-hierarchy/
RUN rm -rf /go-sports-entities-hierarchy/.env
RUN go mod download
RUN chmod +x /go-sports-entities-hierarchy/scripts/*
RUN ./scripts/build.sh

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

ENV GIN_MODE="debug" \
    GQL_SERVER_HOST="localhost" \
    GQL_SERVER_PORT=7777 \
    ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* \
    USER_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_URL="http://localhost:8080/user/me" \
    # GQLGen config
    GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PATH="graphql" \
    GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_ENABLED=true \
    GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_PATH="playground" \
# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 7777

CMD /wait && ./scripts/run.sh
```

**sport_app docker-compose.yml file as below.**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local
services:
  go-sports-entities-hierarchy:
      restart: always
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        context: .
      environment:
        WAIT_HOSTS: postgres:5432
        # Web framework config
        GIN_MODE: debug
        GQL_SERVER_HOST: go-sports-entities-hierarchy
        GQL_SERVER_PORT: 7777
        ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
        USER_MANAGEMENT_SERVER_URL: http://localhost:8080/user/me
        # GQLGen config
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PATH: graphql
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_ENABLED: "true"
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_PATH: playground
      ports:
        - 7777:7777
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redisearch
  go-sports-events-workflow:
      restart: always
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        context: .
      environment:
        WAIT_HOSTS: postgres:5432
        # Web framework config
        GIN_MODE: debug
        GQL_SERVER_HOST: go-sports-events-workflow
        GQL_SERVER_PORT: 7778
        ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
        # GQLGen config
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PATH: graphql
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_ENABLED: "true"
        GQL_SERVER_GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_PATH: playground
      depends_on:
        - postgres
        - redisearch
        - go-sports-entities-hierarchy
```

**user_management app Dockerfile as below:**

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Move to /dist directory as the place for resulting binary folder
WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp -r /build/html .
RUN cp /build/main .

# Environment Variables
ENV DB_HOST="127.0.0.1" \
    APP_PROTOCOL="http" \
    APP_HOST="localhost" \
    APP_PORT=8080 \
    ALLOWED_ORIGINS="*"

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 8080

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD /wait && /dist/main
```

**user_management app docker-compose.yml file as below:**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
  go-user-management:
      restart: always
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        context: .
      environment:
        # Postgres Details
        DB_PORT: 5432
        # APP details
        APP_PROTOCOL: http
        APP_HOST: localhost
        APP_PORT: 8080
        # System Configuration Details
        ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

In sport_app I write below code and get error:

```
client := resty.New()
resp, err := client.R().SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token).Get("http://localhost:8080/user/me")
```

Error is: **Get "http://localhost:8080/user/me": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused:"**
This API(http://localhost:8080/user/me) is written in the user_management app and this is working, I check with the postman.
I already read this question [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873817/dial-tcp-127-0-0-18000-connect-connection-refused-golang-docker-containers?rq=1), but can not solve my problem.
I am new to docker, please help.

Comment: Does All containers run in the same docker machine?

Comment: no, user_management app and sport_app run separately, each app has its own Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: It's going to be much more difficult to link two docker containers together if they're part of different docker-compose.yml files. Is that a necessary part of your design?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary now, I can't change design. What your advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For communicating between multiple `docker-compose` clients, you need to make sure that the containers you want to talk to each other are on the same network.

For example, (edited for brevity) here you have one of the `docker-compose.yml`

```
# sport_app docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  go-sports-entities-hierarchy:
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
  go-sports-events-workflow
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

And the other `docker-compose.yml`

```
# user_management app docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
  go-user-management
    ...
    networks:
      - some-net
networks:
  some-net:
    external: true
```

Note: Your app’s network is given a name based on the `project name`, which is based on the name of the directory it lives in, in this case a prefix `user_` was added.

They can then talk to each other using the service name, i.e. `go-user-management`, etc.

You can, after running the `docker-compose up --build` commands, run the `docker network ls` command to see it, then `docker network inspect bridge`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am a bit confusing. Let me tell you what I did. In user_management app docker-compose.yml file to end off all services I add **networks:
        - um-api_some-net** . and end off this docker-compose.yml I add **networks:
  um-api_some-net:
    driver: bridge** . and in my sport-app docker-compose.yml file to end off all services I add **networks:
        - sport-api_some-net** . and to end off this docker-compose.yml file I add **networks:
  sport-api_some-net:
    external: true**. and as always first I run user_management app then sport-app.

Comment: user_management app runs normally, but when I run (docker-compose up --build) sport-app get this error: **Network sport-api_some-net declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually**. and I create this manually with this command **sudo docker network create sport-api_some-net**. But I get the same error: **Get \"http://localhost:8080/user/me\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused:"**.

Comment: Then I just try to use the service name as you say. instead of **resp, err := client.R().SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token).Get("http://localhost:8080/user/me")** I wrote **resp, err := client.R().SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token).Get("http://go-user-management:8080/user/me")** but get similar error: **Get \"http://go-user-management:8080/user/me\": dial tcp: lookup go-user-management: Try again:"** What I did wrong?

Comment: In this link, you may see my **docker network inspect bridge**command result. https://go.dev/play/p/oxpJn6X_-LV

Comment: here result of **docker network ls** https://go.dev/play/p/uy-PfrJhT2E . last four networks created after run apps.

Comment: Please look at my comments when you have time @Wolfgang . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're running them in the wrong order, docker-compose down -v and then run first the one that creates the network, i.e. the first one. If you need it the other way you can change the network declaration to external to the other one. I gave you an example so you can fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, the network should always be the same, I updated the answer, you can try with `some-net` for all the network declarations

Comment: No problem, thanks, you so help me.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error `( dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused )`
all you need to do is edit your host file `sudo vi /etc/hosts` and remove any IP you don't use and set your new IP with localhost. Please refer to the image :

[Changes to be made in hosts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6An8.jpg)